# Konsole - silence in session 'Default'

Tags: kubuntu, notification, plasma, konsole

Why is my **Konsole** generating notifications every 10 seconds after a keypress in statusbar "*Konsole -- silence in session 'Default'*".

In "Configure Notifications -- Plasma" I can deselect notifications for "Silence in Monitored Session", but why are they generated in the first place?

The distribution is Kubuntu 17.04 with Plasma desktop.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must have inadvertently pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. Press it again to switch it off. I had something similar, but with "Activity in Monitored Session", which pops up whenever you press a key. It can be toggled with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.  Alternetively, you can use the View menu entry in Konsole. See the page [Konsole Command Reference](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/konsole/konsole/commandreference.html#view-menu) for more details.

Comment: Do you also happen to know what this feature is actually intended for? I just can't really come up with a reason why someone would actually want this kind of monitoring...

Comment: @Raven No, but [this page](https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/shell-scripting-tutorial-174/the-konsole-terminal-2938.html) says: **Monitor for Activity:** the session tab shows a special icon if new text appears in the screen area. **Monitor for Silence:** the session tab shows a special icon when no new text appears in the screen area for 10 seconds. These allow you to switch to another session while still monitoring your tab of interest.

Comment: Maybe to get a notification once a job that is more or less continuously writing to stdout is done... /shrug

Comment: Many thanks for this; Shift+Ctrl+I is the shortcut to open dev tools in Firefox in my case so probably inadvertently executed that shortcut while Konsole

Comment: As of this post, the Konsole Command Reference link is broken. I was going to browse for a way to find out which session is causing notifications---a way that is better than clicking all the View menus of all my tabs until I find one that has "Monitor for Silence" checked. Aparrently all my sessions have the same name, so the fact that the notification specifies 'Default' doesn't help.

Comment: @AnaNimbus Thanks, I fixed the link.